# Creating a time table

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I've created a table which has three columns and five rows.

Each row stands for a specific task.

One of these columns, the third column, is dedicated to the time that I have spent to fulfill the task's obligations.

Now what should I write at the header of the third column?

My options are:

1) spent time

2) consumed time

3) taken time

---

Additional info:

I know it is very common to say "It takes me X hours to finish the task". However, I need a very compact phrase that exactly conveys the same information.
Thanks

Comment: Of the three options, "spent time" is the best one (you could also use "time spent"), IMHO, but native speakers might come up with better phrases.

Comment: I agree with @CopperKettle although I'm not a native either. "consumed" feels like it was wasted time. Another viable alternative: duration?

Comment: @laureapresa I think duration suggest something happening constantly over a period of time. However, the task, the mentioned row of the table, can be done in a series of works. The focus is how much time I spend doing that task, no matter how much the works were consistent and continuous.

Comment: I recalled one option: "time expended".

Comment: Whatever verb you choose (spent, consumed, used), it sounds better to say **hours ___ed**.  I'm trying to think of why, exactly, and I think it is because this is essentially a kind of noun phrase: *X hours spent (doing the task)*.

Comment: In project management "Work Completed" and "Work Remaining" are common terms.

Comment: ET (short for Elapsed Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headings for a column showing the **amount of time** it took to **complete a task** might be

> Time Spent
>   Duration
>   Task Time
>   Completed Time
>   Billable Time

in the appropriate **units of measure**

If one included an additional column of

> Allotted time

it would be possible to also track the **accuracy of project forecasts**.

The ordering of **Time**+***verb*** or ***adj***+**Time** is usual among native speakers.

A **succinct way** of expressing this amount to a client might be to use **completion time** or ***time*** **to complete**.

> That will take 5 hours **to complete**.
>   5 hours **completion time**

Comment: Let's hear it for units of measure, as you bring up. Just "**hours**" would probably be fine if nothing else on the chart is also being measured in hours.